# RapidXML loading xml files

Tags: c++, vector, rapidxml

I cannot return the loadings from the xml. Here is the code:

RapidXML xml loader

```
vector<char*> ParseFanbeamGeometry(char* fileName)
{
    xml_document<> doc;
    xml_node<> * root_node;
    // Read the xml file into a vector
    ifstream theFile (fileName);
    vector<char> buffer((istreambuf_iterator<char>(theFile)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    buffer.push_back('\0');
    // Parse the buffer using the xml file parsing library into doc 
    doc.parse<0>(&buffer[0]);
    // Find our root node
    root_node = doc.first_node("FanbeamGeometrySettings");

    vector<char*> fambeamGeometry;
    // Iterate over the fangeometry
    for (xml_node<> * fanGeometry_node = root_node->first_node("FanGeometry"); fanGeometry_node; fanGeometry_node = fanGeometry_node->next_sibling())
    {      
        try
        {
            fambeamGeometry.push_back(fanGeometry_node->first_attribute("geometry")->value());
            fambeamGeometry.push_back(fanGeometry_node->first_attribute("D")->value());
        }
        catch (exception &e)
        {
            e.what();
        }
    }

    return fambeamGeometry;

}
```

main function

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char* fangeofile = "D:\\Projects\\fanbeam\\tools\\rapidxml-1.13\\GeometrySettings.xml";

    vector<char*> fambeamGeometry = ParseFanbeamGeometry(fangeofile);

    float D = atof(fambeamGeometry[1])*N;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FanbeamGeometrySettings>
  <FanGeometry geometry="EquiDistance" D="2"/>
</FanbeamGeometrySettings>
```

The fambeamGeometry properly loads "EquiDistance" and "2", but when it is returned from ParseFanbeamGeometry() to main, the value becomes some weird values, like -18 and -2.

Any suggestions? I have no idea why. How to let the xml loader return what it loads? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `vector<std::string>` instead of

```
vector<char*>
```

then, use `string.c_str()` to convert `string` to

```
char*
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `ParseFanbeamGeometry` is returning a vector of pointers, but the data that they point to will be invalid once `buffer` gets destructed as the function returns.

The correct approach, as you've realized is to pass back `std::string`s instead. That's the idiomatic approach in C++ anyway.

```
vector<std::string> ParseFanbeamGeometry(const std::string &fileName)
```